# How to loop through all sheets but one?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, foreach

I want to loop through sheets and if an interior condition is met then copy this to my "Controle" worksheet.

My code works without the looping.

I have a list in my sheet "Controle" with all the colored cells from all the worksheets. The code must skip the sheet with the name "Controle" because here I copy the cells to.

````
Sub Dubbelewaarden()
Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In Worksheets
    If Not sht.Name <> "Controle" Then
        For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
            If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Controle").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
Next sht

End Sub
```
````

Comment: `Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))` does not have a sheet reference so the active sheet will be assumed and this never changes. Also better to use end(xlup).

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to solve this one. Because I really tried but my workbook crashed again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a case of teing the loop variable to the sheet otherwise the active sheet will be assumed. There are many references to this online.

```
Sub Dubbelewaarden()

Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Controle" Then
        'tie reference to sheet in loop
        For Each cell In sht.Range("A2", sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Controle").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Now if I run the code it doesn't do anything anymore. But thank you for showing me how to tie the reference to a sheet.

Comment: I only just noticed you had a double negative in your If condition so would only operate if sheet name was "Controle".

Comment: Now if I run your code the only sheet he copy's something from is the 3rd sheet named "uren" very weird. It just won't look further then that sheet or something... But still thank you for your help!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code so something else is going on.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the code that gives the cells the interior.colorindex = 3 value.... It need to loop trough all the sheets and search for duplicates and color both the duplicates red with interior.colorindex = 3. This is a differend sub then the one above here btw.

Comment: You will need to do some debugging!

Comment: Your code works fine!! Thank you for your help. The problem was in my other sub!!